# Display snapshot of view android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm building an app to show business cards. I have a scrollView that's showing miniatures of all the cards. What is a good way to display these miniatures? I'm currently using fragments but these are having a huge effect on performance! I guess I could just be using an ImageView and an Image. But how would I get this image from inside the app?

```
    private void displayAvailableCards() {
    int numCards = cm.getSize();

    RelativeLayout rootView =
            (RelativeLayout)myCardsActivityView.findViewById(R.id.frg_myCards_rv_root);

    for (int i=0;i<numCards;i++) {
        int id=addFrame(i+1,rootView);
        addCardToFrame(i,id);
    }
}

private int addFrame(int id,RelativeLayout rootView) {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id - 1);

    FrameLayout fm = new FrameLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    fm.setOnClickListener(this);
    fm.setId(id);
    fm.setLayoutParams(params);

    rootView.addView(fm);
    return fm.getId();

}
private void addCardToFrame(int i,int id) {

    CardViewFragment cvf = getNewCardViewFragment(i);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fs = fm.beginTransaction();
    fs.add(id, cvf);

    fs.commit();
}
```

Comment: You just want a list of images? Why not a `ListView` filled with `ImageView`s?

Comment: @shkschneider Yes that is probably what i would want to do but how would I get images? All the info is currently drawn by the fragment.

Comment: Using `Fragment`s is definitely wrong here. Just make a `ListView` that contains `ImageView`. Bazillions tutorials on this. How you get the images? That is you to answer that, not me: we don't know where you get those images from...

Comment: @shkschneider Ok I will do that and generate the Images at runtime from the fragment somehow. My question was probably a bit vague. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Get rid off the useless `Fragment`s...